# For a beginner, is Java 6 okay or is 7 necessary?

Tags: java, version

I am learning Java for the first time. I currently use Java 6 on my computer, because I have some programs that won't work on 7. Should that be fine for learning Java, or do I need to upgrade to 7?

Comment: Either is fine for learning, you may eventually come accross differences which you can then read into etc.

Comment: There's not much difference between 6 and 7, so just start with 7. Certainly at the beginner-level aspects, there's no huge difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting started, Java 6 is perfectly fine. Java 7's changes are evolutionary rather than revolutionary. Many of Java 7's changes simplify common language constructs via syntactic sugar recognized by the compiler and it's actually quite useful to know what's going on underneath, so going without those features may in fact be better from a learning point of view.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is learning Java, then Java 6 should be just fine. The features introduced in Java 7 aren't all that important that you need to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 will be fine. Very few changes between 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that those programs "would not work with Java 7".  The vast majority of programs written for older versions of Java actually run just fine on Java 7.

And even if they didn't work, Java is designed to work with multiple versions installed on the same machine.  So you could have both Java 6 and Java 7 installed, and configure the troublesome application to use Java 6.

---

However, from the perspective of learning, the stuff added by Java 7 is not that important.  But you want to be able to use it when you are writing real programs ....